# Rails migration : check variable existance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, migration

I'm doing a new rails migration file to move attribute content from model to another model :

```
class StepIdCorrectionForReportSheetTemplate < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
      Report.current.find_each do |report|
        first_sheet = report.sheets.select{ |sheet| !sheet.is_archived }.sort_by{ |sheet| sheet[:order] }.first
        if not report.step_id.nil?
          first_sheet.update( step_id: report.step_id )
          first_sheet.template.update( step_id: report.step_id )
        end
    end

  end
end
```

I got this error:

> undefined method `update' for 
>   nil:NilClass
>   /home/sahnoun/altagem/web/db/migrate/20190208104955_step_id_correction_for_report_sheet_template.rb:7:in
>   'block in change'

I think I should add some other test to check the existence of `report_sheet` and `report_sheet.template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check if `first_sheet.template` is present:

```
 first_sheet.template.update( step_id: report.step_id ) if first_sheet.template
```